# How to scrape all rows from a dynamic table in html with multiple displays using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's link for scraping : https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/

I'm trying to get all the rows of the table (6000+ rows), but I only get the first 500 results. I guess it has to do with the condition of how many rows to display.

I tried almost everything I can. I'm , ALSO, a beginner in web scraping.

My code :

```
# Importing libraries
import numpy as np  # numerical computing library
import pandas as pd # panel data library
import requests     # http requests library
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/'
headers = {'User-Agent': ' user agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.55 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')
league_table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'symbol-table index')
col_df = ['Symbol', 'Company_name', 'Industry', 'Market_Cap']

for team in league_table.find_all('tbody'):
    # i = 1
    rows = team.find_all('tr')
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([len(rows), len(col_df)]))
    df.columns = col_df
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        s_symbol = row.find_all('td')[0].text
        s_company_name = row.find_all('td')[1].text
        s_industry = row.find_all('td')[2].text
        s_market_cap = row.find_all('td')[3].text
        df.iloc[i] = [s_symbol, s_company_name, s_industry, s_market_cap]

len(df) # should > 6000
```

What should I do?

Comment: If you can figure out the "next" button, you should also be able to figure out the selector for how many items to show.  The web developer was kind enough to offer up to 10,000 items to display on one page in the drop-box.  That suddenly makes grabbing and parsing the whole list at one time very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look down the bottom of the html and you will see this

`<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">`

Try using bs4 to find this tag and load the data from inside it, I think this is everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, it's in the `<script>` tags. Pull it and read it in.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
jsonStr = str(soup.find('script', {'id':'__NEXT_DATA__'}))

jsonStr = re.search('({.*})', jsonStr).group(0)
jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['props']['pageProps']['stocks'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
         s  ...                                 i
0        A  ...    Life Sciences Tools & Services
1       AA  ...                   Metals & Mining
2      AAC  ...                Blank Check / SPAC
3     AACG  ...     Diversified Consumer Services
4     AACI  ...                Blank Check / SPAC
   ...  ...                               ...
6033   ZWS  ...         Utilities-Regulated Water
6034    ZY  ...                         Chemicals
6035  ZYME  ...                     Biotechnology
6036  ZYNE  ...                   Pharmaceuticals
6037  ZYXI  ...  Health Care Equipment & Supplies

[6038 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @chitown88!